# Understanding the single-tenant term in azure

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am reading "[What is Azure Active Directory?](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis)". Here there is a glossary showing some basic terms to better understand Azure AD and its documentation. One of these is "Single tenant". According that glossary the definition of this term is "Azure tenants that access other services in a dedicated environment are considered single tenant." Could you help me, to understand this definition with an example, please? Specifically, I would like to understand what are examples of "other services in a dedicated environment" in the Azure Active Directory context.

Comment: Do you have a chance to look into my answer? Is there any other concern?

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn more about [Tenancy in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps).

For "other services", we can think of it as your application or API.

Single-tenant corresponds to multi-tenant.

For Single tenant, It means accounts in this directory only can use your application or API. Use this option if your target audience is internal to your organization.

If you want accounts in any Azure AD directory (for example, your customers from their own tenant) can use your application or API, you should choose multi-tenant.